# How to recognize that ndb query is sorted and how to reverse sort order without knowledge of sort order?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

1. How can I check if query is sorted?

   class Thing(ndb.Model):
     pass

   query = Thing.query().sort(Thing.id)
2. How can I reverse such sort?

Answer (score 2):

`query.orders` will return a `datastore_query.Order`, which has a `reversed` method, so something like:

```
query = Thing.query().order(Thing.id)
[...]
order = query.orders
reversed_order = order.reversed()
new_query = Thing.query().order(reversed_order)
```

If there isn't an order on the query, `order` will be `None`

Comment: What is the order if order is `None` - maybe it is strange question but should be defined - even is not defined directly.